# Confusion with regex expression for valid IPv4 addresses

Tags: linux, grep

I'm trying to write a Regex expression for selecting the valid IPv4 addresses out of a file which contains many valid, invalid(both) type of addresses.
I have already written the Regex for doing that but two of invalid IPv4 addresses are still printing out - 255.255.256.255 and 8.234.88,55
Can anyone help me understanding why these two are printing out with regex that I have put.

```
((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){1,3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)
```

I am using this regex to filter valid IPv4 addresses through the file containing, below listed IPv4 addresses.

```
12.12.12.12
127.0.0.0
255.255.256.255
344.19.0.1.
12.255.12.255
138.168.5.193
256.123.256.123
195.45.13.0
8.234.88.55
1334.0.1.234
196.83.83.191
133.133.133.133
8.234.88,55
203.26.27.38
88.173.71.66
136.186.20.9
241.92.88.103
```

I want to know why this regex expression is matching with 255.255.256.255 and 8.234.88,55 IPv4 addresses.

Comment: Do not post links or screenshots. Instead, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text?more_on=xron.net). People here regard that as evil.

Comment: I have made changes as suggested. Thanks

Comment: `why this regex expression is matching with 255.255.256.255 and 8.234.88,55 IPv4 addresses` It doesn't. Your method of checking if the regex matches is flawed.

Comment: There are over 200+ other Q/A when searching for `regex for IPV4 addresses`. That is the purpose of maintaining a database filled with common questions and their answers ;-) ... However, glad you're getting some good feedback below. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

> why this regex expression is matching with 255.255.256.255 and 8.234.88,55 IPv4 addresses.

It doesn't. It matches parts of that string. Most probably you did:

```
$ echo '255.255.256.255' | grep -E '((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){1,3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)'
255.255.256.255
```

Yay, it works. But the pattern doesn't match the whole like, it matches parts `255.255.25` and `6.255` separately. The `{1,3}` allows the first part to match only once or twice, not necessarily 3 times. Like:

```
 ((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.)((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.)(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)
   25  5                                 .   25  5                                 .                             2    5    6.255
                                                                                                                           ^^^^^ - left over
```

Because of the `{1,3}` the first part may be matched only once. Because `grep` applies regex to part of the string and because the full regex matched, the line is printed.

Similarly for `8.234.88,55` the part `8.234.88` is matched and `,55` is not matched. Is cool to see:

```
$ echo '8.234.88,55' | grep --color -E '(((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){1,3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){1}'
8.234.88,55
^^^^^^^^ - is red
```

To match the whole line do `grep -x` or add anchors `^....$` or most probably you want to change `{1,3}` to `{3}` to match exactly 3 parts.

Answer (score 0):

((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.)

I've tried your expression in C++.
Adding an extra slash before the dot solved here for the comma issue.

It parsed a comma because you are missing a slash, the way it is being written interpretes the dot as "parse any character but EOL".

Also your expression is allowing values to be prefixed by a 0 when you put [01]?

There goes a suggestion on how to tackle the expression: if the it has only one digit, how can it be written? Then 2 digits then 3...

```
(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])
```

Comment: You confuse the escaping of ``\`` required by `regex` with the escaping required by the C++ rules of writing strings as source code. You have to use double ``\`` in the C++ source code but it is, in fact, only one ``\`` in the string. The other one is required by the language. The original regular expression is correct at that point. If wrapped in apostrophes, the `regex` provided in the question can be used as-is in the command line, there is no need for extra escaping.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is not anchored to the beginning and end of the strings. It matches fragments of each line, not the entire line.

Put your `regex` between `^` and `$`.

`^` matches the beginning of the string; `$` matches the end of the string.

If multi-line matching is enabled, `^` matches the beginning of a line, `$` matches the end of a line.

Also, the `regex` slightly incorrect and this makes it match less than it should. An IPv4 address always has 4 components. Because of `{1,3}`, your `regex` allows 2 to 4 components. Combined with the lack of anchors, it finds two matches in the lines you mentioned.

Take a look at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/tzzynw/1).

The `regex` should be:

```
^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$
```